# How to set default locale in ResourceBundleMessageSource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I have two language files in `/resources`:

```
mymessage_de.properties
mymessage_en.properties
```

I want to create a message bundle that should fall back to `_de` by default if the bundle could not be resolved. But being on an english machine, the bundle always falls back to system default. Which is `_en`.

I can disable that by setting `bundle.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false)`, which will then result in an empty message.

Question: how can I set the default locale to use?

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageBundleBlank() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource bundle = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        bundle.setBasenames("mymessage");
        bundle.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        bundle.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        //TODO how can I set a fallback to 'messages_de.properties'?
        return bundle;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractResourceBasedMessageSource.html#setFallbackToSystemLocale-boolean-) for the `#setFallbackToSystemLocale`:

> Set whether to fall back to the system Locale if no files for a
>   specific Locale have been found. Default is "true"; if this is turned
>   off, the only fallback will be the default file (e.g.
>   "messages.properties" for basename "messages").

So, really what you could do here is change your "default" to be `_de` by changing the file name from `mymessage_de.properties` to `mymessage.properties`. You can just make a note in your documentation to that effect.

Comment: Were you able to find your answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

What about switching the locale ?

```
public MessageSource messageBundleBlank() {
        boolean localeSwitched=false;
        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("en"))   {
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);
            localeSwitched=true;
        }
        ResourceBundleMessageSource bundle = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        bundle.setBasenames("mymessage");
        bundle.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        if(localeSwitched)  {
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
        }
        return bundle;
    }
```

Comment: Switching the global locale will have wide impacts on the application itself, eg datetime format, currency format, etc. Thus I'd rather want to stick to the default locale en. Just the default message bundle should not be en...

Comment: That is why I switched it back before the return but yes agreed could impact other application functionality during the method invocation.